# Javascript associative array returns empty/undefined despite being populated inside function

Tags: javascript, return-value, associative-array, dynamic-arrays

I am working on a Javascript function which takes an XML document and creates a multidimensional (as needed) associative array.  Inside the function, the array builds properly however upon returning the Array object, it returns an empty array.

Interesting to note, if I use the push method, and push a literal Array in the form {"index": index, "value":value} rather than using the assignment operator (array[index]=value) it works just fine

For testing I am using the following XML node object (Level_1_node):

```
<Level_1>
    <Level_2>VALUE</Level_2>
</Level_1>
```

Here is the function:

```
function get_array_from_XML(XML_node){
    var XML_array = new Array();
    var child_node;

    for(var i=0; i<XML_node.childNodes.length; i++){
        child_node = XML_node.childNodes[i];
        if(child_node.childNodes[0]){
            if (child_node.childNodes[0].nodeType == 3){
                XML_array[child_node.nodeName] = child_node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            } else {                
                XML_array[child_node.nodeName] = get_array_from_XML(child_node);
            }
        }
    }

    dump(XML_array);  //for my debugging, alerts "LEVEL_2 => VALUE", so everything seems fine

    return XML_array;
}
```

The follow method works, however the return format is undesirable:

```
function get_array_from_XML_using_push(XML_node){
    var XML_array = new Array();
    var child_node;

    for(var i=0; i<XML_node.childNodes.length; i++){
        child_node = XML_node.childNodes[i];
        if(child_node.childNodes[0]){
            if (child_node.childNodes[0].nodeType == 3){
                XML_array.push({
                    "index" : child_node.nodeName,
                    "value" : child_node.childNodes[0].nodeValue
                });
            } else {                
                XML_array.push({
                    "index" : child_node.nodeName,
                    "value" : get_array_from_XML_using_push(child_node)
                });
            }
        }
    }

    dump(XML_array);  //shows the fully populated array

    return XML_array;
}
```

Now when I run `get_array_from_XML(Level_1_node)` it returns an empty array, but `get_array_from_XML_using_push(Level_1_node)` returns

```
{0 => {"index" => "Level_2", "value" => "VALUE"}}
```

Very frustrating.  Any insight is welcome.

Comment: Do you realize that javascript doesn't have associative arrays?  They have arrays and they have objects.  If you want a numeric index, use an array.  If you want a named index, use an object and let each named index be a property.

Comment: One should not use non-numeric "keys" in an array ([]) - apart from string version of integers, which is handled appropriately. That is for objects ({}).

Comment: Although I have heard "Javascript does not use associative arrays," I never had someone go in depth on the nuances.  This clears things up.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, when you do `list['one'] = 1`, what's really happening is that the array's underlying object has the property named `one` inserted with the value of `1`. That property can then be accessed as `list['one']` or `list.one`, i.e. its not an array. You can however have an array of objects as long as index is an actual integer and the object that's being assigned is initialized properly, i.e. `list[1] = { key: value };`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `new Array()` to `new Object()`. The `Array` constructor is *not* for associative arrays; it's for numerically indexed arrays only. Objects themselves double as associative arrays in JavaScript.

```
function get_array_from_XML(XML_node){
    var XML_array = new Object();
    // -------------------^
    var child_node;

    for(var i=0; i<XML_node.childNodes.length; i++){
        child_node = XML_node.childNodes[i];
        if(child_node.childNodes[0]){
            if (child_node.childNodes[0].nodeType == 3){
                XML_array[child_node.nodeName] = child_node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            } else {                
                XML_array[child_node.nodeName] = get_array_from_XML(child_node);
            }
        }
    }

    dump(XML_array);  //for my debugging, alerts "LEVEL_2 => VALUE", so everything seems fine

    return XML_array;
}
```

---

### Using Objects as Associative Arrays

Have a look at the following example:

```
var colors = new Object();
colors['red'] = '#f00';
colors['green'] = '#0f0';
colors['blue'] = '#00f';
colors['black'] = '#000';
colors['white'] = '#fff';

conosle.log(colors['red']); // => #f00
conosle.log(colors['green']); // => #0f0
conosle.log(colors['white']); // => #fff

// Use for..in or Object.keys to iterate over an object
for (var key in colors) {
    console.log(key, colors[key]);
}
// Logs all colors and their corresponding code

Object.keys(colors).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, colors[key]);
});
// Also logs all colors and their corresponding code
```

Note that `colors['red'] = '#f00';` is identical to `colors.red = '#f00';`. The square bracket notation is only really needed when you want to use a string which is an invalid identifier or when you want to use the value of a variable as a property name.

Comment: `Array constructor is for numerically indexed arrays only` - after some years of using JS, I first stumbled over this issue today. Cannot believe it hasn't crossed my way earlier. Thanks for this valuable information!